# jqGrid postData.filter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I want to use the filtertoolbar, but with a server that accept different filter parameters.

I'm trying to find the filter parameters in order to manipulate the postData.

on beforeSearch, I'm trying to extract the filter using:

```
var postData = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
alert(postData.filters);
```

The postData.filter returns undefined all the the time.

Once more thing to note is that the server don't have in it's json request scheme any "filters" notion, so the json request is populated by me.

Here is the functions:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        var pageOffset = (sessionPage - 1) * pageLength;
        var totalList = 0;
        var pageNumber = 0;
        var totalPages = 0;

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'https://vlnx277:7000/vmgr/vapi/rest/sessions/list',
            mtype: "POST",
            postData: sessionListData(pageOffset),
            datatype: "json",
            onPaging: function(pgButton) {
                var requestedPage = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
                if (pgButton == "user") {
                    // find out the requested and last page
                    var lastPage = $("#jqGrid").getGridParam("lastpage");
                    // if the requested page is higher than the last page value 
                    if (requestedPage > lastPage) {
                        // set the requested page to the last page value - then reload
                        $("#jqGrid").setGridParam({page:lastPage});
                        sessionPage = lastPage;
                    } else {
                        sessionPage = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
                    }
                } else if (pgButton == "next_jqGridPager") {
                    sessionPage = +$(".ui-pg-input").val() + +1;
                } else if (pgButton == "prev_jqGridPager") {
                    sessionPage = $(".ui-pg-input").val() - 1;
                } else if (pgButton == "last_jqGridPager") {
                    sessionPage = $("#jqGrid").getGridParam("lastpage");
                } else if (pgButton == "first_jqGridPager") {
                    sessionPage = 1;
                } else if (pgButton == "records"){
                    sessionPage = 1;
                    pageLength = $(".ui-pg-selbox", this.p.pager).val();
                }


                pageOffset = (sessionPage - 1) * pageLength;
                sessionList(pageOffset);


            },

            onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder){
                //alert (index +  " " + sortorder);

                var field_name = "id";
                var sort_direction = "ASCENDING";
                var sortDirectionFields = [];


                //In case no more sorting:
                if (!index){
                  sortingAddion = ',"sortSpec":[{"attName":"id","direction":"ASCENDING"}]';
                } else {
                  var indexPlusSort = index.trim() + " " + sortorder.trim();
                  var multiSortVaribles = indexPlusSort.split(",") // Delimiter is a string
                  for (var i = 0; i < multiSortVaribles.length; i++)
                  {


                        var fieldDirectionPair = multiSortVaribles[i].trim().split(" ");
                        if (fieldDirectionPair[0]){
                                var attrDirection = {};
                                field_name = fieldDirectionPair[0].trim();

                                if (fieldDirectionPair[1] == 'desc') {
                                    sort_direction = "DESCENDING";
                                } else {
                                    sort_direction = "ASCENDING";
                                }
                                attrDirection["attName"] = field_name;
                                attrDirection["direction"] = sort_direction;

                        } 
                        sortDirectionFields.push(attrDirection);

                  }


                  sortingAddion = ',"sortSpec":' + JSON.stringify(sortDirectionFields) ;

                }


                sessionList(pageOffset);


            },
            beforeProcessing: function(res, status, xhr) { 
                pageOffset = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-list-paging-offset");
                //pageLength = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-list-paging-length");
                totalList = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-list-size");
                pageNumber = pageOffset / pageLength + 1;
                //alert(pageOffset + " " + pageLength + " " + pageNumber);
                 if (totalList % pageLength == 0){
                    totalPages = Math.floor(totalList/pageLength); 
                 } else {
                    totalPages = Math.floor(totalList/pageLength) + 1; 
                 }

            },
            /*
            gridComplete: function(data) {

                var postData = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
                var filters = '';
                postData.filters = {};
                //alert ("In grid complete " + $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
                //alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
                //$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData: '{"filters":{}}' });
                alert ("In grid complete " + $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
            },
            */
            loadBeforeSend: function(xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + btoa("xxxxx" + ":" + "xxxxx"));                 
                return xhr;
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", type: "POST"},
            headertitles: true,
            colModel: [
                { label: 'ID', name: 'id', key: true, width: 75 },
                <!--{ label: 'Session Name', name: 'session_name', width: 150, editable: true },-->
                { label: 'Start Time', name: 'start_time', width: 150, editable: true },
                { label: 'End Time', name: 'end_time', width: 150, editable: true },
                { label: 'Owner', name: 'owner', width: 150, editable: true },
                { label:'Session Source Type', name: 'session_source_type', width: 150, editable: true  },
                { label:'Session Status', name: 'session_status', width: 150, editable: true  }

            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            jsonReader: {
                page: function (obj) { return pageNumber;  },
                total: function (obj) { return totalPages; },
                records: function (obj) { return totalList; }
            },
            loadError : function(xhr,st,err) {
                alert("Type: "+st+"; Response: " + xhr.status + " " +xhr.statusText);
            },
            autowidth: true,
            height: 500,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            rowNum: 50,
            rowList:[10,20,30,50,100,200],
            shrinkToFit: true,
            altRows: true,
            rownumbers: false, // show row numbers
            rownumWidth: 25, // the width of the row numbers columns
            //multiselect: true,
            multiSort: true,
            hoverrows: true, // true by default, can be switched to false if highlight on hover is not needed
            caption: "vManager Sessions View Grid", // set caption to any string you wish and it will appear on top of the grid
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('bindKeys');
        //$('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar',{beforeSearch:beforeSearch});
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch : "cn", beforeSearch: function() {
            var postData = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
            var newPostData = '1=1';
            //alert(postData);
            alert(postData.filters);
            //var searchData = jQuery.parseJSON(postData.filters);
            //alert(searchData);
            /*
            for (var iRule=0; iRule<searchData.rules.length; iRule++) {
                newPostData = newPostData + " AND " + searchData.rules[iRule].field + " LIKE '%" + searchData.rules[iRule].data + "%' ";
            }
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData: { filter: newPostData, filters: ''} } );
            */
            return false;
        }});



        $('#jqGrid').navGrid("#jqGridPager", {edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, view: false});
        $('#jqGrid').inlineNav('#jqGridPager',
            // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
            { 
                edit: true, 
                add: false, 
                del: true, 
                cancel: true,
                editParams: {
                    keys: true,
                },
                addParams: {
                    keys: true
                }
            });
    });

    function sessionList(pageOffset){
        //alert(sessionListData(pageOffset));
        $("#jqGrid").setGridParam({ postData:sessionListData(pageOffset)  });
    }

    function sessionListData(pageOffset){
        //alert('{"pageOffset":' + pageOffset + ',"pageLength":' + pageLength + ',"projection": {"type": "SELECTION_ONLY","selection": ["id","start_time","end_time","owner","session_source_type","session_status"] }' +  sortingAddion + '}');
        return '{"pageOffset":' + pageOffset + ',"pageLength":' + pageLength + ',"projection": {"type": "SELECTION_ONLY","selection": ["id","start_time","end_time","owner","session_source_type","session_status"] }' +  sortingAddion + '}';
    }

    function beforeSearch(){
        alert("In search");
        alert($("#jqGrid").getGridParam("postData").filters);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  The postData must contain an object with key "filters".  So I just changed the postData on gridComplete to add an empty "filter":{}, and within the beforeSearch I extract the info out of it, and do delete postData.filters (my server don't accept "filters").

Answer (score 0):

You should verify whether you use `datatype: "local"` or `stringResult: true` option of `filterToolbar`.

Comment: Thanks, the mtype: "POST",
                datatype: "json",   and the stringResult is set to true.

Comment: $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch : "cn", beforeSearch: function() {
    var postData = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
    var newPostData = '1=1';
    //alert(postData);
    alert(postData.filters);